# Mistaken results from Google Geocode API

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

I need to request in google geocode api to get geocodes. I've city, district, number and state and I'm requesting

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={street}, {number} - {district}, {city } - {state} ... `
```

I'm sending a city, but google is returning to another city.

is there a way to force-find geocode in the city that I'm sending?
Or force parameters at query, like:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?city={city}&state={state}
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like Google Maps supports passing in structured address data, only address strings. Consider taking a look at Azure Maps, it has a service where you can pass in each part of your address as separate parameters. This will likely be more inline with what you are looking for. Here is the service documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/search/getsearchaddressstructured

Here are some related resources:

- https://azure.com/maps
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/
- https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/index.html